# Linking an existing React lib

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't seem to find how to integrate my existing project with this react.js library

https://github.com/resin-io-modules/rendition

I've installed and can run the storybook example but cannot reference in my own App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Button, Box, Provider } from 'rendition';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Resin.io Brightness Bar</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>

        <Provider>
           <Box my={3} mx={['auto', 15]}>
             <Button primary emphasized>Click me</Button>
           </Box>
         </Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have tried placing the rendition folder in `/src` and `/node_modules`, neither works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first install this`rendition` npm module.

run `npm i rendition --save` in a command and then `npm start` your project.